# Shorthand Constructor notation

Tags: java, constructor

I was just wondering if there is a 'quick/shorthand' notation in Java for creating a number of the exact same objects, with different names? Same parameters and all that jazz.

Kinda like -

```
private float bal, limit, amount;
private String name, add;
```

But instead for objects

Here's what I'm working with

```
private JTextField nTF = new JTextField();
private JTextField aTF = new JTextField();
private JTextField sTF = new JTextField();
private JTextField bTF = new JTextField();
private JTextField cTF = new JTextField();
```

Comment: You could make an array, then use a loop to populate each entry of the array.  But there's no magic shorthand.

Comment: Create a collection of them and create them using a for loop.

Comment: `private String name, add;` nothing has been created there. Strings are objects too.

Comment: You're not asking for `private JTextField nTF = new JTextField(), aTF = new JTextField() ...`, are you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no quick/shorthand notation in java to create multiple objects in one go.

But you can achieve this by creating a object factory method and calling that method in a loop.

```
// object Factory Method
private XYZ getXYZInstance(){
   XYZ objXYZ = new XYZ();
   // initialization 
}

// Your Code

List XYZList = new ArrayList<XYZ>();
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   XYZList.add(getXYZInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that creates an object with correct parameters:

```
public static JTextField createFoo(){
  JTextField field = new JTextField(1, 2, "foo",);
  field.setFoo("xyz");
  return field;
}

JTextField ntf = createFoo();
```

You can also clone an object and create instance based on existing:

```
 JTextField field = new JTextField(1, 2, "foo",);
 JTextField nTF = field.clone();
```

but this can be a bit more [involved](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Comment: If someone used this in code I was reviewing, there would be lots of red lines.  This is NOT an improvement on the original code.

Comment: It is verbose, it is ugly, it is inefficient ... In short it is NOT an improvement on the original code.  Besides, I don't see the point of the reflection here.  Wouldn't `public static JTextField createFoo(){ return new JTextField(); }` do the same thing???

Comment: @StephenC don't see reflection used anywhere in my code. It is improvement over original because he can write initialization code in a single place, eliminating repetition, since he need to create "exact same object".

Comment: You are correct.  However, the fact remains that this does not improve the OP's use-case, and is wrong on that basis.